# Regex for fail2ban to filter mail from a specific top level domain

Tags: regex, filter, postfix-mta, spam, fail2ban

Background: I'm running a Plesk CentOS 6.7 server with 30+ domains. I'm getting huge amounts of spam from a specific TLD (.top in this case). I'm running SpamAssassin and using RBL list (xbl.spamhaus.org). SpamAssassin is flagging most of these messages as spam, but enough are getting through that my server is getting rate limited by Google's mail servers (due to some of my user's email accounts being forwarded to Gmail). I get ZERO legit email from this domain, and memory usage is up a few percent recently, so I'm trying to save some overhead and improve my server reputation by blocking these messages before they even get to Postfix.

I would like to write a filter for fail2ban that would match connections from this TLD, and ban the corresponding IP addresses.

Here are example log entries:

```
Mar 20 03:12:43 mydomain postfix/smtpd[6557]: connect from whatevermonkey.top[66.199.245.168]
Mar 20 05:07:38 mydomain postfix/smtpd[13299]: connect from someonecat.top[216.169.126.67]
```

So can anyone help with a REGEX that I could plug in to fail2ban that would match all 'connect from' which included the '.top' TLD?

I've been trying to work this up based on my working postfix-sasl filter (below), but my regex chi is not strong enough... Here is my working filter for postfix-sasl which matches failed login attempts:

```
failregex = ^%(__prefix_line)swarning: [-._\w]+\[<HOST>\]: SASL ((?i)LOGIN|PLAIN|(?:CRAM|DIGEST)-MD5) authentication failed(: [ A-Za-z0-9+/:]*={0,2})?\s*$
```

Again, I just want to match IP addresses that are preceded by 'somespammyserver.top' Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might be of help:

```
connect from [\w.]+\.top\[([.\d]+)\]
# look for connect from literally
# followed by \w = a-z0-9_ and . greedily
# followed by .top[
# capture everything that is a digit or a dot into the first group
# (hence the ())
# followed immediately by a closing bracket ]
```

See [a demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/yI2vC2/1).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Running this against my logs with 'grep' fails (no results) but 'grep -P' works perfectly. I'm not sure how fail2ban handles matching (whether or not it is PCRE compatible?) I did create a filter with this regex, and I get the error: "No 'host' group in [regex]". So I think fail2ban has some additional requirements other than simple regex. So I have some more research to do. Thanks again!

Comment: @cmpreshn: You might as well get along with [`connect.+?\.top\[([.\d]+)\]`](https://regex101.com/r/yI2vC2/2)